# angular 8 open mat dialog in mouse clicked location

Tags: dialog, position, angular8, mat

I have a mat grid and I want to set filter for each column.
I  added a button in the mat-header-cell and I wand to open a mat dialog with my filter component.
I want my dialog to open every time near the column the user clicked on (by mouse position)

Thanks
Dvey